# "The" before a subject with a defining clause

Tags: grammar

The title might seem a little odd, but I could not find a way to describe my question. Apologies.

Which article do I have to use "the" or "a"?

- We were discussing ***a*** building that is called The Washington monument.
- We were discussing ***the*** building that is called The Washington monument.

It is not clear to me whether ***a/the*** defining clause I encounter requires "the" or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the speaker expects the building to be unknown to the hearer, they might use *a* to make them aware of the existence of such a building. If the building is assumed to be well-known, they would use *the* to indicate which one they are talking about.

> We visited a house called Greenwood Manor (an invented name).
>
> We visited the Tower of London.